# Replicating Excel Array Cumulative Multiplication in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If have a time series of monthly returns going back 36 months. I need to multiply them month over month to get a 36m compounded return. In excel I use an array function such as `=((PRODUCT(1+(H3:AQ3)/100))-1)*100` where the cells are the time series.

In pandas, I see cumprod is applicable but I need to add 1 to each subsequent month so that I don't get extremely small numbers. How can I do this in python?

sample DF with returns going from old to more recent:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[0.038,
0.041,
0.045,
0.051,
0.05,
0.058,
0.066,
0.061,
0.07,
0.075,
0.082,
0.084,
0.093,
0.072,
0.092,
0.096,
0.096,
0.11,
0.122,
0.114,
0.137,
0.292,
0.158,
0.163,
0.174,
0.175,
0.173,
0.186,
0.186,
0.201,
0.209,
0.189,
0.208,
0.201,
0.205,
0.194596400000013])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `product` method along the column axis (`0`)

```
((df/100 + 1).product(axis=0) - 1) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows you to add a constant to each element by just using the + operator.  So

```
(df + 1).cumprod() - 1
```

should get you what you want.

Comment: Ah.  I see the Exel macro is just going to give you a scalar.  The cumprod method is going to give you the list of cumulative products at each position.  And I also didn't include the percent to fraction and fraction to percent conversions.  So, I am marking Msaino's answer up.